# Unsupported class file major version 66

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin

Any help? I have this problem in Java 22 and Gradle compatibility

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. And this question has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unsupported+class+file+major+version+%5Bjava%5D+%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bgradle%5D